# Vue JS: vuex state not updating the component after change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I created an info-bar, an area I want to update with info from the component. I added it as a child of `App.vue` :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <InfoBar />  // my info-bar
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

To be able to update m`<InfoBar />` from other components, I decided to try using `Vuex` and use `mutations` to change info:

**Vuex Store:**

```
   export const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state:{
            infoBarText: "Text from Vuex store" ,  // initial text for debugging         
        },
        mutations:{
            setInfoBarText(state,text){
                state.infoBarText = text;
            }
        }
```

**infobar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{infoString}} // the result is always "Text from Vuex store"
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "infoBar",
  data() {
    return {
      infoString: this.$store.state.infoBarText      
    }
  }
```

Now, I would like to update the text using the Vuex mutation from other component:

**other.vue:**

```
mounted() {
 this.$store.commit("setInfoBarText", "Text from Component");
}
```

I checked the `state` of `infoBarText` with Vue developer tools and it successfully changed to `"Text from Component"` but it's not changed the text in the component.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Similar but not the same...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be using `computed` instead of `data`, because `data` itself is not reactive once it is assigned. This will fix your issue:

```
export default {
  name: "infoBar",
  computed: {
    infoString: function() {
      return this.$store.state.infoBarText;
    }
  }
}
```

Proof-of-concept:

```js
const infobar = Vue.component('infobar', {
  template: '#infobar-template',
  computed: {
    infoString: function() {
      return store.state.infoBarText;
    }
  }
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    infoBarText: "Text from Vuex store", // initial text for debugging         
  },
  mutations: {
    setInfoBarText(state, text) {
      state.infoBarText = text;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    updateText() {
   store.commit("setInfoBarText", "Text from Component");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.22/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <InfoBar></InfoBar>
  <button @click="updateText">Update text</button>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="infobar-template">
  <div>
    {{infoString}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: using computed still does not work for me.... :(

Comment: spent all day looking for this answer!  can't believe 'computed doesn't crop up more time in answers ;-)

Comment: i had same kind of problem, i am already using in computed, but still can not work, does any one has ans?

Comment: @Tyguy7 Were you able to find the answer? Computed does not work for me either.